# Technological unemployment

Tags: unemployment, technology, technological-progress

I am doing a project on technological change in the job market, that is the substitution of routine occupations and increasing demand for high-skilled jobs.
I have done some research on this and now I am seeking extra sources of advice. I was wondering if anyone could recommend me a model which would be applicable to present technological change or job-market flows with? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could let us know the papers you found, some of the background experience you have, and some more specifics.

[This](https://www.bu.edu/econ/files/2015/05/Robots_Are_Us_3-29-20151.pdf) might be a useful paper nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am basing my research on Autor, Levy and Murnane (2003) paper "The skill content of recent technological change", as well as variety of other papers including or Greatz, G. and Michaels, G. (2015), Robots at work. However, what I am looking for is a more general Labour Economics or Productivity-related model, like the one I could find in the economics textbook.

Comment: The paper you linked does incorporate productivity in it, and has models utilizing it. This textbook: http://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/Modern_labor_economics__theory_and_public_policy_0.pdf may also be useful. 

Do you think you are looking for something like: $$Worker\ Productivity = Technology + Work Culture$$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely have a look at it. Regarding your question about the regression - no, I am looking for something more like: Change in employment = Change in use of technology (technology proxy: value added, R&D investment) + control variables.

Answer (score 0):

Two interesting papers with theory and evidence [Robots and Jobs: Evidence from US Labor Markets](http://pascual.scripts.mit.edu/research/robots_jobs/robots_jobs.pdf) and [Artificial Intelligence, Automation and Work](http://pascual.scripts.mit.edu/research/ai_restrepo/ai_restrepo.pdf)